# Twilio Call disconnects when user selects "#" pound key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, twilio

Twilio simply disconnected/ hangup call when the user selects pound key "#" in a key press event.

```
   response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Gather action: post_to do
      r.Play TWILIO["RECORDINGS_URL"] + "recording.wav"
      r.Say "We have recieved no input. Thank you."
      end
      r.Hangup
    end
```

In this scenario when the user selects # key while the recording is being played, Twilio skips to the next name to r.Say and hangup the call. And the event is not triggered to Application server with selected Digits as "#".

When the user selects other than "#" options i.e. 0-9 or * it works fine.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

By default the `<Gather>` verb actually has an [attribute `finishOnKey` set to "#"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-finish). When `finishOnKey` is set Twilio will listen to all the input and post it to the `action` URL when that key is pressed. If there is no input other than the `finishOnKey` then Twilio treats it as no input and will move on in the TwiML and, in your case, hang up.

To fix this if you are expecting a certain number of input characters then I would set `finishOnKey=""` (empty string) and `numDigits="X"` where X is the number of digits you want entered. Alternatively, if you don't have a fixed number of digits you are waiting for, you can set a timeout which will either post all the digits entered during the time or continue on through the TwiML if nothing was entered.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Its works Fine as expected now, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this was the answer, could you accept it as correct? Then other people viewing this question will be able to see that this answer will help them. Thanks!

Comment: If the # key is entered once its working as expected and if the # is pressed twice or thrice or more at a time it disconnects
even the numdigits is set to 1 and finishonkey is set to "".

r.Gather action: post_to, timeout: 60, numDigits: 1, finishOnKey="" do

please advice

Comment: It might be best to open this up as a new question with all the details of the setup you have now. Drop a link to the question and explanation in here and I'll take a look!

Comment: I have opened a new question please look into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958105/twilio-call-disconnects-call-when-user-selects-pound-key-multiple-times thanks.